# jquery fileupload plugin, how to cancel upload file process

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to cancel the click event of file upload if some condition is true, something like

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    start: function (e, data) {
        //How to acheive this?
        if(some condition 1){
            alert('You can upload file';
            //show the file browser window and upload file as normal
        }
        else{
            alert('You cannot upload file');
            //do not show any file selection window and do not upload any file
        }
    }
});
```

I am using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Comment: And what did you find out? Does it work?

Comment: No, so far nothing found

Comment: Just to get the story straight, what is it exactly that you are after? When the file starts uploading you want to cancel uploading? Or do you just want to disable the upload button?

Comment: based on a condition, I want to reject the default click event of file upload.

Comment: Please post any workaround if you found one